# Update a record only if today's date is greater then the date in the Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have records in the database looking like the following:

```
RES_ID | RES_CHECK_IN  | RES_CHECK_OUT
----------------------------------------
  1685 |   08/10/2015  | 12/10/2015
  1684 |   24/10/2015  | 28/10/2015
  1683 |   20/09/2015  | 22/09/2015
   105 |   03/04/2015  | 06/04/2015
```

I want to update only `RES ID` 105 because today's date `(01/10/2015)` is bigger then the `CHECK OUT DATE of RES ID 105`. I tried doing this:

Model:

```
function update_columns_lock($res_id)
{
   $data = array('IS_COLUMNS_LOCKED_AFTER_CHECKOUT' => 1);
   $this->db->where('RES_ID' ,$res_id);
   $this->db->update('reservations',$data);
}
```

And the execution:

```
$today = time();
if ($today > strtotime($row->RES_CHECK_OUT)) {

    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->Reservations_model->update_columns_unlock($row->RES_ID);
}
```

Which seems to just randomly update the reservations.. no with the logic i wanted. what do i miss here?

Comment: @Epodax it is already set to this. someone edited my code..

Comment: What field type is `RES_CHECK_OUT`?

Comment: Have you found a solution @IlanHasanov ?

Comment: @Epodax yes. posted my solution very simple

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a issue with your date format. The below code should help you out as it creates a format that strtotime understands.

```
$tmp_convert_time = date_create_from_format("d/m/Y",$row->RES_CHECK_OUT);

if ($today > strtotime(date_format($tmp_convert_time, 'd/m/Y'))) {
   <CODE HERE>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
if (strtotime(date()) > strtotime($row->RES_CHECK_OUT)) {
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->Reservations_model->update_columns_unlock($row->RES_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
function lock_columns_after_checkout()
{
    $custom_sql_command = 'UPDATE reservations SET IS_COLUMNS_LOCKED_AFTER_CHECKOUT = 1 WHERE DATE(RES_CHECK_OUT) < DATE(NOW())';
    $this->db->query($custom_sql_command);
}
```